# Is every odd positive integer of the form $P_{n+m}-P_n-P_m$?

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, analytic-number-theory, prime-numbers

> I am looking for a comment, reference, remark, or proof of three conjectures as follows:
>
> **Conjecture 1:** *Let $x$ be an odd positive integer.  Then there exist two integers $n, m \ge 2$ so that  $$x=P_{n+m}-P_n-P_m,$$ where $P_n$ is the $n^{th}$ prime.*

My calculations the conjecture 1 true for $x=1, 3,\dotsc, 10^7-1$ and $x = 5.4371349x10^7$, $\cdots, 5.4375349x10^7$

A general of the conjecture above as follows **(but weaker)**:

> Let every integer $r_0$ exist positive integer $x_0$ such that every odd number $x \ge x_0$  has the form $x=P_{n+m+r_0}-P_n-P_m$, where $m, n \ge 2$ (PS: inspired from the comment of Lev Borisov be low)

Or simpler:

> > ***Conjecture 2:** Is every odd positive integer of the form $P_{c}-P_a-P_b$ ?*

**See also:**

- [Goldbach's weak conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goldbach%27s_conjecture)

**A stronger comjecture 2**

> > **Conjecture 3 ([Maillet's conjecture](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1206.0149.pdf))** *Is every even positive integer of the form $P_{a}-P_b$*

I have just computed the conjecture 3 is true with $x=2, 4, \cdots, 10^6$ and $3873$ numbers $x = $$9.82197492x10^8$$,$ $\cdots$$,$ $9.82226054x10^8$

**Example:**

$2=5-3$;

$4=7-3$;

$6=13-7$;

$8=13-5$;

$10=17-7$

**See also:**

- [Goldbach's strong conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goldbach%27s_conjecture)

Comment: You might as well assume that $m \geq 2$, since otherwise $x$ is even.

Comment: Why the "computer science" tag? Why the "prime ideals" tag? You know, there's no law that says you must use five tags – you're allowed to use fewer.

Comment: I’m sorry, I think the result can checked by Computer

Comment: So what values of n and m gave rise to the x that is 10^7-1?  Gerhard "Suspect A Typo In Exponent" Paseman, 2018.06.28.

Comment: I am sorry, I didn't print $m, n$ so please waiting me. @GerhardPaseman

Comment: Conjectures on prime constellations should imply this is possible even with $m=2$.

Comment: @GerhardPaseman When You ask, it is 1 AM in my country, I was going to sleep. So now the answer. Click link as follows to view. In the file, I define that. $Amn=P_{m+n}, Am=P_{m}, An=P_n, C=P_{m+n}-P_m-P_n$ [the answer in this text file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1R1Ffl3xLKsjIVIB2Gu63MnZl8wbs7hc4)

Comment: Thank you. I prefer to just have a single pair of values. In the meantime, I have convinced myself that m and n exist and should not be much larger than 10^7.  Gerhard "Thanks Again For Your Link" Paseman, 2018.06.30.

Comment: Indeed it seems that there is no need to link to a text file to give the simply stated answer to @GerhardPaseman's question.  As your file indicates, $m = 6787300$ and $n = 6787562$ (not much larger than $10^7$, for reasonable values of "not much larger"), so $P_m = 118988791$, $P_n = 118993759$, and $P_{m + n} = 247982549$.

Comment: Yes, there are many numbers $m, n$ so that $P_{m+n}-Pm-P_n=10^7-1$

Comment: "Is every odd integer..." would be a version of the title more consistent with the question.

Comment: Yes, thank You very much. I edited again. I have just checked this true with x=1, 3,....12342955 @MattF.

Comment: I agree Wojowu's comment: Conjectures on prime constellations should imply this is possible even with $m=2$.

Comment: @Zhi-WeiSun Thank You very much, but with m=2 it is very difficulte checked with $x$ large. I have a algorithm to fast checked this result. If You can help me I will comunication with You.

Comment: @Zhi-WeiSun Can I publish this conjecture on your journal?

Comment: @MattF., that was my edit in the title, and I forgot the old maxim that 'any' should never be used as a quantifier, because it can easily be read *both* as 'every' *and* as 'some'.  I agree that the current title is better.

Comment: Now I checked this is true with $x=1,3,⋯,54373881$; $(54373881 = 5.4373881*10^7)$ @Zhi-WeiSun

Comment: It is a nice observation. I doubt that there is any way to find a proof, since the number of a prime is a rather fickle invariant. I suspect that if you ask about $P_{m+n+1}-P_m-P_n$ the results might be similar. It might be more reasonable to ask whether one can prove that supremum over $x$ of minimum $|a+b-c|$ for all $x=P_c-P_a-P_b$ is bounded. This is a notably weaker statement, but it seems to me to be more hopeful.

Comment: I agree that may be, every odd integer $x$ of the form $P_{m+n+1}-P_m-P_n$. Thank You for your help @LevBorisov

Comment: @LevBorisov Please see the question above. I wish You are co-author of the general case, do You agree?

Comment: I have just computed the conjecture 3 is true with $x=2, 4, \cdots, 10^6$ and $3873$ numbers from $[982197492$, $982197494$, $\cdots$, $982226054]$=$[9,82197492.10^8$, $\cdots$, $982226054.10^8]$

Comment: By "integer", do you mean "positive integer", or do you really mean *integer*?

Comment: I mean positive integer, can You help me correct?

Comment: @ĐàoThanhOai - The usual terminology is to call elements of $\mathbb Z$ *integers*, and to say that an integer $n\in\mathbb Z$ is *nonnegative* if $n\ge0$ and *positive* if $n>0$. Also, if you want a user to be notified, you can use the `@` symbol.

Comment: Just some remarks. I believe that Conjectures 1 and 3 are out of reach at present by being "binary additive problems in the primes". Conjecture 2 is straightforward by being a variant of the ternary Goldbach problem. See also the following related MO entries: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/202979/a-variant-of-the-goldbach-conjecture and https://mathoverflow.net/questions/253324/two-equivalent-statements-about-primes

Comment: @GHfromMO I hope that. Thank You very much

Comment: @GerryMyerson Today, I see that maybe conjecture 1 equivalent to Goldbach's conjecture https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goldbach%27s_conjecture or Corollary of the Goldbach's conjecture, because $P_n+P_m=P_{n+m}-x=y$. Where $x$ is an odd positive integer less than $P_{n+m}$ then $y$  is an odd positive integer less $P_{n+m}$. But maybe we must prove that $P_n+P_m \le P_{m+n}$. Is my remark right?

Comment: If $y$ is a sum of two primes, and a difference of two odd numbers, then $y$ is even, not odd.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I don't know what Conjecture 1 has to do with Goldbach's conjecture, may you help me? @GerryMyerson

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The **conjecture 3** is mentioned [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/111196/name-of-a-conjecture-on-difference-of-prime-numbers) and [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1206.0149.pdf), in which it is called the Maillet conjecture.

The **conjecture 2** is true.

It can be seen by rewriting $n=P_c−P_a−P_b$ as $P_a+P_b=P_c-n$, and it has a solution as long as the sets $\left\{x|x=P_a+P_b\right\}$ and $\left\{x|x=P_c-n\right\}$ have nonempty intersection. Call the two sets $X$ and $Y$ respectively, and let $A_N$ denote the elements of a set $A$ which is not greater than $N$.

We have $|X_N|=O(\frac{N}{logN})$, and a result of [Montgomery and Vaughan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goldbach%27s_conjecture#Rigorous_results)
 shows that $|Y_N|≥\frac{N}{2}-CN^{1-c}$ for some $C$ and $c$.
As $|X_N\cup Y_N|≤\frac{N}{2}+n$ and
$|X_N|+|Y_N|≥\frac{N}{2}+n$ for sufficiently large $N$, it turns out that the two sets have nonempty intersection.

Comment: I have voted your answer. I will accept your answer in next some days, but now I also need the answer for conjecture 1 and conjecture 2. I changes the title of question to get the answer for conjecture 1 and 2.

Comment: Edited to answer conjecture 2.

Comment: I am sorry, I don't see the bounty symbol on  your answer.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't an answer to conjecture 1, just an elaboration of things others mentioned.

There is every reason to think that the answer to conjecture 1 is yes and even that for fixed $m \gt 1$ we have that for each  odd integer $x \geq 3$ there are infinitely many $n$ with $p_{n+m}-p_n-p_m=x.$ We don't know that there is even one, however we can say with good precision how the number of solutions *should* be expected to grow as $n \rightarrow \infty.$ Computations always (seem) to conform to this with good fidelity as far as checked. I'll explain that a bit and then point out that that fixing $m=2$ would likely not be the most fruitful way to find a solution.

So with $m=3$ and $p_3=5$ solving $p_{n+3}-p_n-5=15$ amounts to finding two primes $p_N$ and $p_n$ with

- $p_N-p_m=20$
- $N-m=3.$

We do not know that $p_N-p_m=20$ infinitely often. For each even integer g define $\pi_g(X)$ to be the number of pairs $(p_N,p_n)$ with $p_N-p_n=g$ and $p_N \leq X.$ Then $\pi_2(X)$ is the number of twin primes up to $X$ We don't know that this grows without bound but can expect that it is assymptotic (in some sense which could be made precise) to $C_2\frac{X}{\ln^2X}$ and that the constant $C_2=\prod_p(1-\frac1{(p-1)^2})$ with the product over the odd primes.

There is a similar constant $C_g$ for each even $g.$ Namely $C_g=C_2\prod_p\frac{p-1}{p-2}$ where the product is over odd primes which  divide $g.$

So $p_n+20$ is expected to be prime more often that $p_2$  but about as often as $p+10.$ i.e. $\pi_{20}(X) \sim \pi_{10}(X)\sim \frac{4}{3}\pi_2(X).$ That is a prediction which holds up quite well as far as checked.

For an amazing exposition of this read [Heuristic Reasoning In The Theory of Numbers](https://aimath.org/~conrey/portland/polya_Heuristic_reasoning_in_number_theory.pdf) by Polya.

But our goal had an extra condition. Want something like to have

$p_n,p_n+6,p_n+14,p_n+20$ to all be prime but $p_n+h$ be composite for $h=2,4,8,10,12,16,18.$ It is possible to similarly predict how often that happens up to $X.$ Summing over finite number of cases would give a prediction for the number of solutions of the given problem.

$m=2$ is a little easier but I wanted to use a different value.

But where is it most fruitful to look for solutions  to $p_{n+m}-p_n-p_m=x$?

Here is a graph for $p_{n+m}-p_n-p_m=101$ with $n+m\lt 200.$

I find $168$ solutions. here is a graph.
[image]

Of the $168$ solutions, $61$ of them have $m \in\{34,35,36,37,38\}$ and the ratio $\frac{n}{m}$ ranges from $3$ to $5.2$

Using $p_k \sim {k}{\ln{k}}$ one might be able to argue that for fixed $r=\frac{n}{m}$ ( really $r$ in some small range like $[3,5]$) there is a narrow range of $m$ values that would be worth searching first. Perhaps the best $r$ (given $x$) could be estimated. I would have guessed $r \sim 1$ is best, but that seems not to be the case based on this one computation. Perhaps the optimal range is past $m+n=200.$

Comment: I hope that you will research detail about this conjecture? Thank You very much.